# How can I show the keys I used on the bottom left of my screen

Tags: interface

I see a lot of tutorials on YouTube that toggle on the history thing on the bottom left corner.
[image: The thing that displays the pressed shift button]f

Sorry for asking such amateurs question because I am.

Comment: are you sure it is a history thing? it looks more like what a screencast addon do, i.e. displays the key that is used

Answer (score 1):

you can download screencast keys here: https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys

You install it via Preferences -> add ons -> install.

In the viewport you can activate it by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> and then tap on screencast keys. Then check the checkbox at the top.